# Configure a command line to execute on log in

Tags: command-line, login, startup-applications, hp-touchpad

Every time I reboot my Ubuntu 14.10, my touchpad drive(synaptics) resets to default configuration.
Is there a way to restore my sysclient settings after rebooting? Alternatively; how can I configure a command to execute every time I log in?

The command to set my touchpad correctly is:

```
 synclient VertScrollDelta=-120 && synclient HorizScrollDelta=-120
```

Comment: how are you making settings changes now?

Comment: Every time I start a session I open the terminal and execute this:

synclient VertScrollDelta=-120 && synclient HorizScrollDelta=-120

How can I program this to execute every start ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the command to your startup applications: Dash > "Startup Applications" > Add the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&synclient VertScrollDelta=-120 && synclient HorizScrollDelta=-120"
```

The break of 15 seconds is to allow the desktop to load before the settings to change (else the command would break).

On next login, it should work (after 15 seconds). You can experiment a bit with the break. Probably the 15 seconds is on the save side.

#### Alternatively

You can (in general) create an autostart item manually (which gives you full control)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Touchpad settings
Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&synclient VertScrollDelta=-120 && synclient HorizScrollDelta=-120"
Type=Application
```

Copy the code above, paste in into an empty file and save it as:

```
settings_touchpad.desktop
```

In `~/.config/autostart`. On next login the command in the `Exec=` line will be executed.

Comment: I used the Startup Applications way and it worked. Thank you!